# Unable to properly deploy my NestJS API with my Angular Azure Static Web App pipeline

Tags: azure, nestjs, github-actions, nrwl-nx, azure-static-web-app

I'm running an NX Monorepo for two apps. One Angular App and one NestJS API. I'm trying to deploy an Azure Static Web app using a GitHub Action.

My pipeline runs smoothly with no errors (yml below). My Angular App builds and deploys smoothly. The NestJS API builds and deploys smoothly. No errors.

When I visit my deployed app, all calls that go to /api just 404 error.

How do I troubleshoot this? I can't find any useful Nodejs logs in the Azure metrics | logs section of their UI.

Here is my Github Action yml:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - develop

env:
  NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS: true

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_FOO_BAR_123 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: 'upload'
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: '/' # App source code path
          api_location: 'dist/apps/api' # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: 'dist/apps/myApp/en' # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_FOO_BAR_123 }}
          action: 'close'
```

I see both sections for App and API end in success.

```
...
---End of Oryx build logs---
Finished building app with Oryx
Api Directory Location: 'dist/apps/api' was found.
Warning: If the application is exporting static html files, i.e., 'next export', consider setting 'IS_STATIC_EXPORT' flag!
Using 'staticwebapp.config.json' file for configuration information, 'routes.json' will be ignored.
Copying 'staticwebapp.config.json' to build output
Starting to build function app with Oryx
---Oryx build logs---
...
---End of Oryx build logs---
Function Runtime Information. OS: linux, Functions Runtime: ~4, node version: 16
Finished building function app with Oryx
Zipping Api Artifacts
Done Zipping Api Artifacts
Zipping App Artifacts
Done Zipping App Artifacts
Uploading build artifacts.
Finished Upload. Polling on deployment.
Status: InProgress. Time: 0.0288762(s)
Status: Succeeded. Time: 15.0509071(s)
Deployment Complete :)
Visit your site at: https://foo-bar-123.azurestaticapps.net
Thanks for using Azure Static Web Apps!
Exiting
##[debug]Docker Action run completed with exit code 0
##[debug]Set output static_web_app_url = https://foo-bar-123.azurestaticapps.net
##[debug]Finishing: Build And Deploy
```

So in the case above ... I head to https://foo-bar-123.azurestaticapps.net and view my perfectly working Angular application, but all calls to https://foo-bar-123.azurestaticapps.net/api will 404.

Any insight? I can't deploy my app.

EDIT: Interestingly enough, if i deploy my same code directly to an Azure Function it will throw the following exception. The exception can then be found in Azure Logs under 'AppExceptions'.

```
Result: Failure
Exception: Worker was unable to load function main: 'Unable to determine function entry point. If multiple functions are exported, you must indicate the entry point, either by naming it 'run' or 'index', or by naming it explicitly via the 'entryPoint' metadata property.'
Stack: Error: Worker was unable to load function main: 'Unable to determine function entry point. If multiple functions are exported, you must indicate the entry point, either by naming it 'run' or 'index', or by naming it explicitly via the 'entryPoint' metadata property.'
at /azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js:2:13853
at t.LegacyFunctionLoader.<anonymous> (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js:2:14092)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at o (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js:2:12538)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

So now maybe I can figure this error out, and then somehow link my static web app to an Azure Function manually.